# Dart Regex Matching

Tags: dart

I want to check via regex in dart whether a line contains string such as ABS_D0 or ABS_D1, or ABS_D2 etc upto ABS_D40 and also ABS_DX.

```
 var dcc1= "ABS_D0 4, 5, 158, b";
  var dcc2 = "ABS_D1 3, 5, 157, b";
  var dccEnd = "ABS_DX";
```

If line contains matching string then line is split via comma and stored in list.
example

```
 ABS_D0 4, 5, 158, b should become list[0]=0,list[1]=4,list[2]=5,list[3]=158,list[4]=b



ABS_D1 3, 5, 157, b should become list[0]=1,list[1]=3,list[2]=5,list[3]=157,list[4]=b
```

Comment: you should use a simple example to demonstrate the problem you have. like looking for strings abc or def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying which tpe the list elements must have. The one containing "b" is clearly a string, but should 158 be a string or an integer?
I'll make it a string for now, you can always use `int.parse` if you want it as an integer.

```
final absRE = RegExp(r"ABS_D([1-4]?\d|X)\s*");
List<String> matchABS(String line) {
  var match = absRE.firstMatch(line);
  if (match == null) return null;
  var result = [match[1]]
  result.addAll(line.substring(match.end).split(",").map((s) => s.trim());
  return result;
}
```

The regular expression matches "ABS_D" followed by either a number in the range 0..40 (well, it accepts up to 49 actually, but I assume that's not a problem) or "X". Then the code splits the rest of the line on commas.

Comment: There was a typo in the example, it was missing the `r` in front of the regexp string. That made the `\d` not work correctly. Try it with a `r` in front, then it should work with the `\d` as well.